# How to use Spray's logRequestResponse in tests with debug level?

Tags: log4j, akka, slf4j, spray, spray-test

I am trying to follow [this advice](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/rc9bYO_SxU8) to debug my Spray routes, i.e. using `logRequestResponse`. I am using debug logging level. However, no debug messages appear on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `logRequestResponse` directive takes an implicit `LoggingContext` parameter. LoggingContext will log to an implicit akka actor system if there is one in scope (see its Scaladoc for what it will do in other cases). There is an implicit actor system in scope in Spray Testkit, so if you are using that, that's probably the one that will be in scope. That loads from the standard locations (`application.conf`, `reference.conf`) so if you want to customise the config, you can do

```
override def testConfig = ...
```

Wherever you load the config from, it should contain at least

```
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

to make debug logging show up.

Also, check the config file of your underlying slf4j logging implementation (e.g. log4j) to see where the log statements are being written and what are the minimum log levels in that config file, because that also affects the verbosity of the logging.